# Connect two Restcomm SMSC

Tags: sms-gateway, smpp, restcomm

I have requirement of connecting two Restcomm SMSCs over SMPP, and route a message via them.

RestcommSMSC-1 (as client) --- SMPP ---- RestcommSMSC-2 (as Server)

I have read documentation, but that doesn't seem to  help much. How I can achieve this?