# Establish SS7 connection between two Restcomm SMSC

Tags: sms-gateway, smpp, restcomm, ss7

I have setup two Restcomm SMSCs on different PCs, that are part of same network. I want to establish SS7 connection between them, with one behaving as server and other as client.

Then i want to send an SMS from client to server. In this I have to configure all SS7 layers on both SMSCs to establish a connection and route SMS between them. I have a very basic knowledge of SS7.

How can i configure this connection, is there any guide to it? If not tell me roadmap how to learn this in a smart way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect two Restcomm SMSC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686616/connect-two-restcomm-smsc)